# Does the chinese letter mean the number, one?

Tags: translation, meaning, mandarin, vocabulary

As I browsing around on the internet, I was looking at what a sentence meant in English. But the issue is that I was not sure if this is the Chinese letter for "1" or does it have a different interpretation.

[image]

I am talking about is this letter ^. It's the letter that looks like a dash but has that little thing at the right end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is chinese number one. For the whole phrase, it is normally used like `改编自XXX同名小说`, means "edited from the novel with the same name from XXX"

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` as Arabic numerals。

`〇一二三四五六七八九十` for normal use in China (since ancient china).

`零壹贰叁肆伍陆柒捌玖拾` for financial use in China, like accounting or bank transaction application.

Comment: oops, forgot this, ```〇``` or ```零``` for zero.

Comment: It's possible to [edit] to add them in.

Answer (score 1):

What you think is a caret （^） on the line is just the font style, the character is 1 = 一， yì

改编自....... 有一眼..........同名.......小说作品
gǎibiānzì (yǒuyìyǎn) tóngmíng xiǎoshuōzuòpǐn
Adaptedfrom (this is a pen name, nom du plume) same name novel
Adapted from You Yiyan's novel

Comment: I think the caret ^ functions as an up arrow, pointing to the 一 above.

Comment: Look in the picture at 有， 作 ，you see the same: a horizontal line 一 with a little bump on the end. It's the font.

Answer (score 0):

We are not sure whether or not it is "one". And when I see 同名小說作品. I think that whether or not 有一眼 is the writer who write novel(同名小說作品).

In this kind of situation, Google can provide help. I google [有一眼](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=-1xxXuyVEqOSr7wPrbWP4A4&q=%E6%9C%89%E4%B8%80%E7%9C%BC&oq=%E6%9C%89%E4%B8%80%E7%9C%BC&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i7i30j0j0i30j0i7i30l2.4547.20713..22801...1.0..0.49.626.18......0....1..gws-wiz.....0..0i131j0i5i30.C0acCaAPYWU&ved=0ahUKEwis_6XI1KLoAhUjyYsBHa3aA-wQ4dUDCAU&uact=5) and I found that there are several books, of which the author is 有一眼.

There is probability that 有一眼 is a writer who writes books.